# Show done items in current calendar week

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

For my weekly report at work I use the org-mode (what else?). The custom agenda I am using is specified in my `.emacs` file as follows:

```el
 '(org-agenda-custom-commands (quote (("W" "Weekly Meeting" 
   ((tags "TIMESTAMP_IA>=\"<-1w>\"/DONE" 
     ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote (tag-up))))) 
    (tags "TIMESTAMP_IA>=\"<-1w>\"/ABANDONED" 
     ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote (tag-up))))) 
    (tags "TIMESTAMP_IA>=\"<-1w>\"/FAILED" 
     ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote (tag-up))))) 
    (todo "URGENT" ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote (tag-up))))) 
    (todo "IN PROGRESS" ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote (tag-up))))) 
    (todo "PENDING" ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote (tag-up)))))) nil
    ("test.html")))))
```

Thus, I can see which tasks are urgent, which I am currently working upon and which tasks have been delegated to other people and are pending to be done. Furthermore, I can see what tasks have been done within the last week, which were abandoned and where I failed to deliver the desired result in the last week. (the default export is for different purposes)

Now to my question: As far as I experience it I can only see what I have done/abandoned/where I failed within the last 7 days. A more suitable view would be to see what I have done in the current calendar week. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using an agenda view instead of a todo view.  Setting `org-agenda-span` to `week` and `org-agenda-start-on-weekday` to 0 will show the current week starting on Sunday.  We can use `org-agenda-skip-function` to filter out any item not in a done state.  By default this will hide everything unless we also set `org-agenda-start-with-log-mode`.

Putting it all together gives:

```el
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("W" "Weekly review"
               agenda ""
               ((org-agenda-span 'week)
                (org-agenda-start-on-weekday 0)
                (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode t)
                (org-agenda-skip-function
                 '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'nottodo 'done))
                 )))
```

Comment: That was nice except that it does not capture any repeat tasks that got done during the last week. Any workarounds there?

Comment: You'll have to turn on logging mode to record past activity and logging view to see it. Hit `vl` in the agenda.

Comment: my logging is on `(#+STARTUP: hidestars indent logdone logrepeat logreschedule logredeadline logrefile logdrawer)` and I tried vl in agenda. But no luck. I only see non-repeat tasks marked done

Comment: @deshmukh I changed the line with `org-agenda-start-with-log-mode` to `(org-agenda-start-with-log-mode '(closed state clock))` and I see items that I closed, repeating items whose state changed, and items that received a clock. (Credit to [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52994/org-mode-agenda-show-list-of-tasks-done-in-the-past-and-not-those-clocked/53007#53007).)

Comment: Note, if `org-agenda-custom-commands` is not defined you will need to change the first line to `setq org-agenda-custom-commands`.