# org-mode weekly summary with one entry per DONE task and total time to complete

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want my weekly summary to list all the tasks I completed in a given week, ideally with an **inline** report of the total time each of those tasks took to complete.

Furthermore, it would be even more ideal if these tasks could be shown in a hierarchical / TODO view rather than an agenda view, so you could see them in context with their parents.

Finally, if possible, I'd also like to include any tasks that I worked on (clocked in/out) but didn't complete.

I'm currently using the code from [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8163/24144), which does give me a chronological list of tasks that are marked "DONE". The problem with this approach is that it lists the task multiple times for each clock-in/out. I just want one line per task.