# Org-mode agenda: Show list of tasks done in the past, and not those clocked

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394394/orgmode-a-report-of-tasks-that-are-done-within-the-week) and [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8150/show-done-items-in-current-calendar-week), I want to show an agenda view with all items marked as "DONE" in the last two weeks, but without the lines `Clocked: (1:00) DONE Some task` (because for that I only care about the totals and use a `clock-report` dynamic block). I would also like to restrict to second-level items only.

I tried this code and succeeded in restricting to second-level headings only:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("W" "Weekly review"
               agenda ""
               ((org-agenda-span 'week)
                (org-agenda-start-on-weekday 1)
                (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode nil)
                (org-agenda-skip-function
                 '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp "^\\*\\* DONE "))
                 )))
```

If I set `org-agenda-start-with-log-mode` to `t`, then `Clocked: ...` lines show, e.g.:

```
Monday     30 September 2019 W40
  gtd:        10:49-10:59 Clocked:   (0:10) DONE some task
  gtd:        10:50...... Closed:     DONE Some other task
```

If I set it to `nil`, then `Closed: ...` lines do not show.

Also, if I set `org-agenda-span` to 14, to include the past 14 days, it shows 14 days starting from today.

How can I include only `Closed: ...` lines, and list tasks in the past?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To include only `Closed: ...` use:

```lisp
(org-agenda-start-with-log-mode '(closed))
```

To show the past 14 days offset the start day:

```lisp
(org-agenda-start-day "-14d")
```

This results in:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'org-agenda
  (add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
               '("W" "Weekly review"
                 agenda ""
                 ((org-agenda-start-day "-14d")
                  (org-agenda-span 14)
                  (org-agenda-start-on-weekday 1)
                  (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode '(closed))
                  (org-agenda-skip-function
                   '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp "^\\*\\* DONE "))))))
```

The statement is wrapped inside `with-eval-after-load` to make sure that this doesn't throw an error if org-agenda is not yet loaded.

You might also want to include archived items with:

```lisp
(org-agenda-archives-mode t)
```

---

*Note:
Use <kbd>C-h v</kbd> to describe a variable like `org-agenda-start-with-log-mode` to see the possibilities or <kbd>M-x custmoize-variable</kbd> to customize it (this shows all possibilities in the customize interface).*

Answer (score 1):

I used Hubsian's suggested solution, however, found that the `org-agenda-custom-commands` variable appears to only be created after the agenda is opened for the first time in an emacs session. This causes an error when loading emacs after closing and reopening:

`Symbol's value as variable is void: org-agenda-custom-commands`

So instead, I've modified it to create the variable (and keep the "Agenda and all TODOs item that is created with you first open the agenda dispatcher with <kbd>C-c a</kbd>):

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
             '(("W" "Weekly review"
                agenda ""
                ((org-agenda-start-day "-14d")
                 (org-agenda-span 14)
                 (org-agenda-start-on-weekday 1)
                 (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode '(closed))
                 (org-agenda-archives-mode t)
                 (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp "^\\*\\* DONE "))))
               ("n" "Agenda and all TODOs"
                agenda ""
                ((alltodo "")))
              ))
```

`setq org-agenda-custom-commands` creates the variable `org-agenda-custom-commands` instead of appending to the existing variable by changing `add-to-list` to `setq` and removing the `'` before the variable name.

Additionally, we need to wrap the Weekly review item that's being created in an additional set of parenthesis to make it a list since we're creating a new list variable and not appending new entry to an existing one. This is why there are now two `(` at the start of the `'(("W" "Weekly review"` line and an additional at the end the last line.

Note: more information on the options available when creating custom commands can be found by running `C-h v RET org-agenda-custom-commands`.

*Edit: formatting, better explanation and added: "Agenda and all TODOs".*

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate: say how that change made a difference?

Comment: Yes, please clarify which part of your 9-lines of example is the one that makes the difference (and fix the alignment of your lines while you're at it).

Comment: Apologies, first time answering, is that better now?

Comment: Indeed, my code starts with `(setq org-agenda-custom-commands ...)` and I never ran into this error.

Comment: Edited my solution to address this by using `with-eval-after-load`.